# Why would the onChange event of InputText not fire in Blazor?

Tags: events, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following razor markup in a blazor component:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name">Contact: </label>
    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="Contact.Name" @onchange="NameChanged"></InputText>
</div>
```

When I modify the contact name on the form and tab out of the control the `NameChange` method is never called. Is there something else that I need to do in order to get the `onChange` event to trigger?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot do `@bind-value` and `@onchange` because bi-directional binding subscribe to the `onchange` event.

But you can do it manualy :

```cs
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name">Contact: </label>
    <InputText id="name" Value="@Contact.Name" ValueChanged="NameChanged" ValueExpression="() => Contact.Name" ></InputText>
</div>

@code {
    private void NameChanged(string value)
    {
        Contact.Name = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try using on input (when typing every symbol) or on blur - when navigating away from a field.

```
<InputText id="name" @bind-Value="Contact.Name" @oninput="NameChanged" @onblur="NameChanged"></InputText>
```

`bind-value` is using `@onchange` to update the component value. So you can't use them together.

From MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

*Using @bind with the CurrentValue property () is essentially equivalent to the following:*

```
<input value="@CurrentValue"
    @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => CurrentValue = 
        __e.Value.ToString())" />

@code {
    private string CurrentValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you cannot do bind-value and  @onchange same time

Comment: This is correct, it would be great to expand on this to explain why and what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 5):

I found a much shorter and simpler variant.

```html
<input @bind="searchString" @bind:event="oninput" @onkeyup="SearchChanged" >
```

Any method can then be called with @onkeyup.

Comment: The problem with this is that binding will occur during any input event.  The `SeachChanged` method will only be called when the user releases a key.  If, for example the user copies and pastes data into the field then the input will change triggering the binding, but the user did not release a key, so your `SearchChanged` method will  ever be called.

Comment: The simple answer in the general case is to put your logic in your property setter.  In my case a year ago when I posted this, I did not have the ability to do that because this was library code, so I had no way to access the properties.  Also I did not want to program this into properties everywhere, it would've defeated the purpose of the Blazor component that I created.

Comment: yes, property setter logic seems to be the most straight-forward to me as well, every other approach i can think of introduces to much complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recommendeds you use

```html
<input @bind="YourValue" @bind:event="onchange" @bind:after="YourHandler" />
```

[see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: In modern Blazor this is the correct way. Note that you will need to be at at least .net 7 for this to work though.