# Call function after input in textbox

Tags: c#, input, blazor

I currently have an input tag that will call my GetExtensions(string pathname) function but I'm trying to figure out how to only call this method after the textbox has been filled out.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fileSelector" id="fileSelector" 
    @bind="FileFilter.PathName" 
    @oninput="@(e => GetExtensions(e.Value?.ToString()))"/>
```

How can I pass the value of the textbox to the function only when the textbox has been filled out / focus has been lost?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666336/6621862

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `@onfocusout` instead of `@oninput`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fileSelector" id="fileSelector" 
    @bind="FileFilter.PathName" 
    @onfocusout="GetExtensions" />

@code {
    private void GetExtensions()
    {
        // FileFilter.PathName will contain the input value
    }
}
```

Or:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fileSelector" id="fileSelector" 
    @bind="FileFilter.PathName" 
    @onfocusout="() => GetExtensions(FileFilter.PathName)" />

@code {
    private void GetExtensions(string pathName)
    {        
    }
}
```

Or you can use `@onchange` but `@onchange` cannot be used with `@bind` so you have to manually update `FileFilter.PathName`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fileSelector" id="fileSelector" 
    value="@FileFilter.PathName" 
    @onchange="GetExtensions" />

@code {
    private void GetExtensions(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        FileFilter.PathName = e?.Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `@onchange` `EventCallback` parameter. `@oninput` technically also works, but is called on each input that happens on the element.

I personally use a mixture of the two in my components to update my objects as the user types.

Check this BlazorFiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/imbjwfzt

Code:

```
<input @onchange="InputChanged" @oninput="OnInput" />

<div>@_changeValue</div>

<div>@_inputValue</div>

@code {
    string _changeValue;
    string _inputValue;

    void InputChanged(ChangeEventArgs e) {
        _changeValue = e.Value?.ToString();
    }

    void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _inputValue = e.Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

In your case, update your code like this: